# How to remove symbolic link from directory in Fedora?

Tags: linux, terminal, lfs

I was trying to create symbolic link to directory in Fedora.

```
$ sudo ln -sv $LFS/tools
```

Then this error occurs.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link './tools': File exists
```

How do I remove symbolic link to that directory

Comment: Have you tried `rm`?

Comment: Note that when `ln` says "failed to create symbolic link", it means *it did not create* a symbolic link. So perhaps there is nothing to remove.

Comment: If a file or directory named "tools" exists in your current working directory, I don't think `ln`  will overwrite it. I think that's what the error message is about. If it does exist and is something you want to replace, you can add the `-f` option to `ln` to force it to overwrite the existing file or you can use `rm` to delete it before running `ln` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple
Use `rm -rf` and that link name of directory
It will forcefully remove the link of that directory

Comment: Why would you need to remove a link recursively? That sounds like a recipe for a bad mistake.

Comment: You can also use only rm to delete it